# Issues with the material table updating when using paginator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, paging, cursors, angular-material-table

I've searched and I've searched and I've searched, I can't find an answer to this.

I am using Angular Firestore to fetch data (tried both *snaphotChanges* and *valueChanges*). The code works.

However, if the data changes on the backend, the material table row on the UI only refreshes automatically when either I am showing all the data or if I disable paging. However, when paging is enabled, the UI resorts to show that the data got updated, but it does not refresh the cell value until I move the cursor on the row to force a refresh. I don't know if it's a bug or if I am doing something wrong.

I made a video showing what happens: https://youtu.be/SN6EFc6Vqm8

```
// Have this in my service. It works  
getContactsByLimit(limit) {
    return this.afs
      .collection("users")
      .doc(this.user.currentUserId)
      .collection("contacts", ref =>
        ref
          .orderBy("id", "desc")
          .limit(limit)
      )
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

---

```
  // The paginator declaration
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

---

```
// This works
this.contactsSubscription = this.contactsvc
      .getContactsSnapshotChangesByLimit(3) 
      .subscribe(contacts => {
        // This works, I get new data.
        this.dataSource.data = contacts;  
      });
```

---

```
// HTML template
<mat-paginator class="paginator" 
  [length]="15"  // This breaks the refresh
  [pageSize]="3" 
  [pageSizeOptions]="[2,3,5]" 
  (page)="pageEvent($event)"></mat-paginator>

// The automatic refresh does not work if I set 
// the length to be > 3 in this case (unless I move 
// the mouse on the table).
```

The UI should refresh with new data whether the length > pageSize or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was using trackBy to track by ID.  I added a timestamp field in my document and started tracking by timestamp.

```
 <table [dataSource]="dataSource" [trackBy]="trackByTimestmamp" mat-table>
```

and

```
trackByTimestmamp(index, item) {
    return item.timestamp;
}
```

This forces the material table to update the table when the timestamp changes.